# Can't make ListBox selections show in TextBoxes

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, listbox, excel-2016

The ListBox selections are not being displayed in the corresponding TextBoxes as intended. Despite the code logic to concatenate and display selected values from the ListBox into the TextBoxes, the TextBoxes remain empty.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ListBoxSector.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
    
    OptionButton1.Caption = "Nota Unica"
    OptionButton1.Value = True
    OptionButton2.Caption = "Multiples Notas"
    
    ' Especifica la hoja de trabajo donde se encuentra la columna
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla")
    
    ' Encuentra la última fila en la columna A con datos
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Llena la ListBoxSector con los valores de la columna A a partir de la fila 4
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "A").Value <> "" Then ' Evitar celdas vacías
            ListBoxSector.AddItem ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        End If
    Next i
   
    ' Muestra la fecha de hoy en el TextBoxFecha en el formato deseado
    TextBoxFecha.Value = Format(Date, "dd ""de"" mmmm ""de"" yyyy")
    fechaOriginal = TextBoxFecha.Value ' Almacena la fecha original
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    ListBoxSector.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
End Sub
 
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    ListBoxSector.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
End Sub

Private Sub ListBoxSector_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim selectedPersons As String
    Dim selectedFunctions As String
    
    TextBoxPersona.Text = ""
    TextBoxFuncion.Text = ""

    ' Especifica la hoja de trabajo donde se encuentra la columna
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabla")
    
    ' Encuentra la última fila en la columna A con datos
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Verifica si se ha seleccionado algún elemento en la ListBox
    If ListBoxSector.ListIndex >= 0 Then
        ' Construye cadenas con los nombres y funciones correspondientes de los sectores seleccionados
        For i = 0 To ListBoxSector.ListCount - 1
            If ListBoxSector.Selected(i) Then
                For j = 4 To lastRow
                    If ws.Cells(j, "A").Value = ListBoxSector.List(i) Then
                        If selectedPersons <> "" Then
                            selectedPersons = selectedPersons & " "
                            selectedFunctions = selectedFunctions & " "
                        End If
                        selectedPersons = selectedPersons & ws.Cells(j, "B").Value
                        selectedFunctions = selectedFunctions & ws.Cells(j, "C").Value
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
        Next i
    End If
      TextBoxPersona.Text = ""
    TextBoxFuncion.Text = ""
    ' Muestra los nombres y funciones correspondientes en los TextBox
    TextBoxPersona.Value = selectedPersons
    TextBoxFuncion.Value = selectedFunctions
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBoxFecha_Change()
    If CheckBoxFecha.Value Then
        ' Marcar el checkbox, restablecer la fecha
        TextBoxFecha.Value = Format(Date, "dd ""de"" mmmm ""de"" yyyy")
    Else
        ' Desmarcar el checkbox, restaurar la fecha modificada
        TextBoxFecha.Value = fechaOriginal
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxFecha_Change()
    ' Actualizar la fecha original cuando el usuario modifica manualmente
    fechaOriginal = TextBoxFecha.Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButtonEnviar_Click()
    ' Verificar si se ha seleccionado un sector en ListBoxSector
    
        MsgBox "Selected Persons: " & selectedPersons
MsgBox "Selected Functions: " & selectedFunctions
    
    If ListBoxSector.ListIndex = -1 Then
        MsgBox "Por favor, selecciona una Cámara de Turismo.", vbExclamation, "Campo Obligatorio"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If TextBoxNota.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox "El campo 'Nota' no puede estar vacío.", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I added:

```
MsgBox "Selected Persons: " & selectedPersons
MsgBox "Selected Functions: " & selectedFunctions
```

To see what was doing the code and see if it was creating the chains but remains empty.

Comment: Place a Breakpoint in this line `selectedPersons = selectedPersons & ws.Cells(j, "B").Value`. The program stops every matching iteration, when you can check the actual value of `selectedPersons` and the other variables . (After check continue with `F5`

Comment: I put the breakpoint and when I select the optionbutton to select several, it would not be generating the string of values ​​of selectedPersons and selected Functions

Comment: This means that your code didn't stop at the breakpoint?

Comment: Exactly, he just ignored it. But when the OptionButton1 is active and i select a value the breakpoint activates and shows the value of the chain empty

Comment: If it stops and command `?ws.Cells(j, "B").Value` in the immediate window not show anything, means that you have no data in that cell.

Comment: I added

`Debug.Print "Value in column B: " & ws.Cells(j, "B").Value
Debug.Print "Value in column C: " & ws.Cells(j, "C").Value`

and when i select an option with the checkbox1 shows:


**Value in column B: Sra.Mariana Farjat -
Value in column C: Presidente**


but, with checkbox2 stops printing the values when i mark the options

Answer (score 0):

At least I get the root of the issue.

When you select the OptionButton2, this means `fmMultiSelectMulti`.
In this case the ListBox_Click event is **not invoked** on selecting the items in the ListBox.
The change event not too appropriate to resolve the issue because it is invoked at every click of an item in the list.

- What can be done to add a CommandButton to the Form, and the whole Event procedure assign to the CommandButton_Click event.
- If after selecting the necessary rows in the ListBox, you have to move to another control on the Form, then **Exit** is the suitable event.
  ( ListBox_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)  )